# Groovy. Appending nodes while using MarkupBuilder and XMLSlurper

Tags: groovy, xmlslurper, markupbuilder

My question is with Groovy and appending a node while using MarkupBuilder and XMLSlurper.

Can someone tell me why when I run this code up to the first println my output shows the target-line as:

```
<target-line>0</target-line>
```

But when I run it through to the second println my output for target-line is now:

```
<target-line>
    <target-line>7</target-line>
</target-line>

// Complete code
import groovy.xml.*
public class AppendNodeExample {
    //Constructor
    public AppendNodeExample() {

    }

    def CreateNewMessage() {
def dataToProcess = '<response><applied-edits><line><id>0100</id>' +
                 '<flag><mnemonic>TRA</mnemonic><message>TRA Message ' +
                 'Info.</message></flag><flag><mnemonic>REB</mnemonic>' +
                 '<message>REB Message Info.</message><target-line>' +
                 '<target-line>7</target-line></target-line></flag><flag>'+
                 '<mnemonic>UNB</mnemonic><message>UNB Message Info.</message>'+
                 '</flag></line></applied-edits></response>'
def rootNode = new XmlSlurper().parseText(dataToProcess.replaceAll(':','-') )

def newXmlFile = new StringWriter()
def xmlCladNew = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(newXmlFile)

xmlCladNew.response() 
{

    'applied-edits'()
    {

        rootNode.'applied-edits'.line.each
        { appliedEditsLine ->

            line 
            {
                id(appliedEditsLine.id)

                appliedEditsLine.flag.each
                { nodeLineFlag ->
                    flag 
                    {
                    mnemonic(nodeLineFlag.mnemonic)
                    message(nodeLineFlag.message)
                        'target-line'('0')
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}

def rootNodeNew = new XmlSlurper().parseText(newXmlFile.toString())
// First println
          println XmlUtil.serialize(rootNodeNew)

rootNodeNew.'applied-edits'.line.each 
{ line -> 

    line.flag.each
    { lineFlag ->
        if (lineFlag.mnemonic == 'REB') {

            lineFlag.appendNode({'target-line'('7')})
        } else {
            // Remove the target-line node
            lineFlag.'target-line'.replaceNode {}

        }
    }
}

XmlUtil.serialize(new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {mkp.yield rootNodeNew} )
          // Second println
println XmlUtil.serialize(rootNode)


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reformatting your code so it's readable and follows any sort of guidelines makes it easier to see what's wrong:

```
import groovy.xml.*

public class AppendNodeExample {

    //Constructor
    public AppendNodeExample() {
    }

    def createNewMessage() {
        def dataToProcess = '''<response>
                              |  <applied-edits>
                              |    <line>
                              |      <id>0100</id>
                              |      <flag>
                              |        <mnemonic>TRA</mnemonic>
                              |        <message>TRA Message Info.</message>
                              |      </flag>
                              |      <flag>
                              |        <mnemonic>REB</mnemonic>
                              |        <message>REB Message Info.</message>
                              |        <target-line>
                              |          <target-line>7</target-line>
                              |        </target-line>
                              |      </flag>
                              |      <flag>
                              |        <mnemonic>UNB</mnemonic>
                              |        <message>UNB Message Info.</message>
                              |      </flag>
                              |    </line>
                              |  </applied-edits>
                              |</response>'''.stripMargin()

        def rootNode = new XmlSlurper().parseText( dataToProcess )

        def newXmlFile = new StringWriter()
        def xmlCladNew = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder( newXmlFile )

        xmlCladNew.response {
            'applied-edits' {
                rootNode.'applied-edits'.line.each { appliedEditsLine ->
                    line {
                        id( appliedEditsLine.id )
                        appliedEditsLine.flag.each { nodeLineFlag ->
                            flag {
                                mnemonic( nodeLineFlag.mnemonic )
                                message( nodeLineFlag.message )
                                'target-line'( '0' )
                            }
                        }
                    } 
                }
            }
        }

        def rootNodeNew = new XmlSlurper().parseText( newXmlFile.toString() )
        // First println
        println XmlUtil.serialize( rootNodeNew )

        rootNodeNew.'applied-edits'.line.each { line -> 
            line.flag.each { lineFlag ->
                if( lineFlag.mnemonic == 'REB' ) {
                    lineFlag.appendNode { 'target-line'( '7' ) } 
                } else {
                    // Remove the target-line node
                    lineFlag.'target-line'.replaceNode {}

                }
            }
        }

        XmlUtil.serialize(new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {mkp.yield rootNodeNew} )
        // Second println
        println XmlUtil.serialize( rootNode )
    }
}

new AppendNodeExample().createNewMessage()
```

In the second println, you're printing out the original `rootNode` which you haven't done anything to, so it just contains the original `<target-line>7</target-line>` node.